# Active Employees by Month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data

```
Hire Date      Termination Date
1/28/2019             4/16/2019     
2/18/2020             
9/17/2018             3/12/2020
```

I need to find how many active employees the company had for each month. So far, I tried the formula below, and it came pretty close. But I need accurate numbers.

```
{=SUM((IF('Employee Roster'!C$2:C$5000<>"",'Employee Roster'!C$2:C$5000,"")<=EOMONTH(A38,0))*(IF('Employee Roster'!D$2:D$5000="",1E+100,'Employee Roster'!D$2:D$5000)>EOMONTH(A38,0)))}
```

For the formula, Employee Roster C is the hire date, A38 is the Month column in my final table, Employee Roster D is the Termination Date.

At the end, I wish my final table to look like below

```
Month             Active Employees
February 2019           100
March 2019              129
April 2019              150
...
```

Comment: If someone is terminated mid-month, are you counting as "active" for that month? Assuming yes, but just confirming.

Comment: Yes, they are considered active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Construct a list of all the month start dates of interest.

  - In O365, you can use the formula `=EDATE(EOMONTH(MIN(Hires),-1)+1,SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(EOMONTH(MIN(Hires),-1)+1,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0),"m")+1)-1)`
  - In other versions, you could construct a list of months manually.

and it will `SPILL` down as far as required.  But there are other ways to create this list, even manually.

- In the adjacent cell to the first month, enter the formula:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((IF(Termination="",TODAY(),Termination)>=A2)*(Hires<=EOMONTH(A2,0)))
  ```

and fill down as far as required.

**Algorithm**

If a person is an employee during a given month, then

- His termination date must be after or equal to the start of that month

  - *If there is no termination date, it is set to `TODAY()`*
- His hire date must be equal to or prior the end of that month

*In the screenshot, I formatted the month as `m/d/yyy` so as to emphasize it needed to be the first of the month; but you can format it as `mmmm yyy` to match your desired report requirement*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't work as I am still getting the same number.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The results I am getting are not accurate. For example, I know my company has exactly 612 active employees as of today, yet the formula above gives me 610. The same problem occurs with previous months, but the difference keeps growing.

Comment: @byrak79 You will need to provide sample data that results in an incorrect result with the formula I provided, in order to go further.  You can edit your original question and post the data as text which can be copy/pasted (as you did initially, although that seems to calculate correctly), or perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Hey Ron, I figured out the problem. Two accounts had blank weird start dates. I dont know what I did but it works now. Thanks.